# Sending a struct over udp socket

Tags: c, sockets, struct, udp, pack

I'm writing a client/server based on udp and I want to send a sequence number along with with each datagram, I have tried to send the struct over udp using #pragma or pack structs with no luck.

```
typedef struct {
 char buf[BUF_SIZE];    //buffer size is 4096
 int seq;
} pack;
```

When I try to send a file with size 131094 bits, I receive the file at the other side with 135300 bits. my question is, is there a way to do it without Serialization?

Comment: This is entirely possible, even if potentially not wise, you need to give us more code and more information to assist you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending data from a struct, socket programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000257/sending-data-from-a-struct-socket-programming)

Comment: Yes this is entirely possible - if there's a problem it is in your sending/receiving code.

Comment: @Joe This is entirely *impossible,* *unless* there is a bug in the code. UDP datagrams arrive intact and entire or not at all. TicTac you will need to post your code.

Comment: @EJP My response was to "is there a way to do it without serialization". To which the answer is yes. Why he has a mismatch between what he thinks he sent and what he thinks he received is a different issue entirely.

Comment: @TicTac Neither 131094 nor 135300 is evenly divisible by 8. Ergo you neither sent nor received that many bits.

Comment: What @EJP says plus it's not possible to transfer an arbitrary number of bits with your 'pack' struct because there is nothing to describe how many bits are in 'buf'.  This would be a big problem with the last datagram.  I don't understand the bit fixation anyway - neither the network or the disk subsystem can handle anything less than bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = recvfrom(sd,&pkt,sizeof(pkt),0,(struct sockaddr *)&clt,&l);
```

Here `n` will be either -1 or the size of the entire received packet, including the sequence number word.

```
write(fd, pkt.buf,n)
```

Here `n` is still the size of the entire received packet. You're not subtracting the size of the sequence number from the length of the packet, so you're writing extra bytes per write. You should be calling

```
write(fd, pkt.buf, n-sizeof int);
```

However it seems to me that the packets should also contain their own length, to cope with the case where the data isn't a multiple of 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thank you i changed that , but still didn't solve the problem